# JTextPane keypress emulation

Tags: java, jtextpane

I have a JTextPane integration that should perform predefined steps on keypress events. If I type manually it seems to work fine. But I have to emulate keypress events on this integration for test purposes. The test enviroment is such that the given JTextPane is not added to any other controls. I tried to use Robot class, after set the visibility and editablety of the JTextPane to true, and requesting focus. The problem is that I could not see any key press events coming, and the content of the JTextPane is still empty. 
  Please give me some advice.
  Thank you,

Peter

Answer (score 0):

> The test enviroment is such that the
>   given JTextPane is not added to any
>   other controls

Then the component is not visible on the screen and cannot accept focus, therefore the Robot won't work.

I'm not sure but you might be able to use

```
textPane.dispatchEvent(....).
```

Or if that doesn't work then you can use:

```
textPane.getDocument().insertString(...);
```